# How to configure Spring boot web app server to server external content plus use default resources directory?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have small spring boot app that both downloads and serves up content.

**Some Context: Replicate and Serve**

The app runs on a disaster-recovery box. It uses spring scheduler to periodically download via a rest api a set of html pages from our wiki/confluence, then serves up those same .html files via embedded tomcat.

i.e. so 'instructions' are available in the DR data center in case the main data center or datbase/etc is unavailable.

A two-trick pony. In only a few lines of code.  *Thank you spring!!!*

**Serving External Content with Spring Boot**

I got instructions how to serve up external content from Spring boot using a custom WebMvcConfigurer [ see code below]

**However Lost Default "For Free" Behavior**

Adding the custom configurer "took away" all the "url mapping stuff I get for free" with spring boot, e.g. automatically making "/resources" directory availble to the browser as a url. e.g. "resources/styles/site.css" served as "http://localhost/styles/site.css"

I confirmed: when I commented out the "WebMvcConfigurer", spring boot's default "url mapping to file system" behavior worked as per documented.

**Question**

How can I *extend* WebMvcConfigurer to *keep* all the "for free" default spring boot file-to-url mappings but add an external mapping, i.e. tell tomcat to serve up content from this external directory?

Thanks!

**Code**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@Slf4j
/**
 * Exists to allow serving up static content from the filesystem
 */
class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    AppConfig appConfig

    @Override
    void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/exported/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:${appConfig.outDir}/")

        // I had to add this line to expose 'styles/'  as a url path
        registry.addResourceHandler("/styles/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/public/styles/")



    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Spring MVC by default serves static content from the following directories:

```
"classpath:/META-INF/resources/",
"classpath:/resources/",
"classpath:/static/",
"classpath:/public/"
```

But WebMvcConfigurer, as presented in the question, *suppresses* these defaults that's why only files found in "external" location are served.

However, `addResourceLocations` method actually supports an array of strings, so you can do the following:

```
@Configuration
class StaticResourcesConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:///tmp/external-resources/", 
                                      "classpath:/static/");
    }
}
```

Now if you put, say, `/tmp/html-external.html` and `src/main/resources/static/html-internal.html` then (assuming the host/port is `localhost:8080`) both requests will be served:

```
HTTP GET: http://localhost:8080/html-external.html
HTTP GET: http://localhost:8080/html-internal.html
```

Of course, the if you have some controllers they'll also work

**Update 1**

Based on the comment, in order to map the `http://localhost:8080/` to some predefined `index.html`:

1. Add `src/main/resources/static/index.html`
2. Modify the `WebMvcConfigurer` as follows:

```
@Configuration
class StaticResourcesConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:///tmp/external-resources/", 
                                      "classpath:/static/");

        registry.addResourceHandler("/")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/index.html");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ths works. and i'll accept your answer: one follow-on: how do I keep mapping '/' to 'index.html' ? Adding an extra '*.html' resource handler does not appear to work:, i.e.       registry.addResourceHandler("*.html").addResourceLocations("/static")

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean that http://localhost:8080/ should serve index.html? I should check that out...

Comment: Pleae See Update 1 to the answer. Please let me know if it works for you. thanks

Comment: fwiw, I could not get the second "addResourceHandler" to work--i..e mapping root to index.html..-- neither in groovy nor java--for spring boot app w/ Spring boot 2.2.1